# Preg_Replace Change URL

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to grab content from another one of my site which is working fine, apart from all the links are incorrect.

```
    include_once('../simple_html_dom.php');


    $page = file_get_html('http://www.website.com');


$ret = $page->find('div[id=header]');


echo $ret[0];
```

Is there anyway instead of all links showing  link  to have the full link?   using preg replace.

```
   $ret[0] = preg_replace('@(http://([\w-.]+)+(:\d+)?(/([\w/_.]*(\?\S+)?)?)?)@', 
       '<a href="$1">http://fullwebsitellink.com$1</a>', $ret[0]);
```

I guess it would be something like above but I dont understand?

Thanks

Comment: I do not understand as well. Also you should use `DomDocuemnt` instead of simple html dom IMHO. Url services are available with NetURL2, everything else is done with XPATH much better than with a regex. You could try with NetURL2 as well and [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) in an intermediate form.

Comment: I need to use regex for the project im on, but i dont understand it. I've mangaged to pull data from another site but all the urls are wrong.

Comment: Replace all the links using `->find('a')`, don't use a regular expression. It's bound to miss... just about everything.

Comment: There never is the need to use regex in any project. You can always write your own function and call that. It will even allow you to improve your method over time without changing the rest of the software. Otherwise learn regex, this is no regex tutorial site. But this one is: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys, mini-tech can you explain how i would do this? ->find('a')

Comment: @hakra How well will `DOMDocument` cope with badly-formed (or simply non-XML-like) HTML documents? XML parsers are in general a bad choice for web-scraping, as they are designed for processing well-formed data.

Comment: Very good, it has a superb `loadHTML` method, so next to a XML parser it also has a HTML parser. A very good one btw. That is basically why nobody needs simple html dom any longer and the library is not maintained since longer, has bugs and all such. So actually just a tip :). In case you miss CSS selectors, you might want to learn a bit about Xpath. Also I have the feeling there is a CSS selector available soon as a handy add-on library.

Comment: @hakra Ah, thanks, that I did not realise. I thought it was just a wrapper around libxml, and would therefore expect well-formed input.

Comment: @hakra OTOH, I have absolutely no idea what you mean by this: "There never is the need to use regex in any project. You can always write your own function and call that." In what sense can creating a function remove the need to use a regex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question doesn't really explain what is "incorrect" about the links, but I'm guessing you have something like this:

```
<div id="header"><a href="/">Home</a> | <a href="/sitemap">Sitemap</a></div>
```

and you want to embed it in another site, where those links need to be fully-qualified with a domain name, like this:

```
<div id="header"><a href="http://example.com/">Home</a> | <a href="http://example.com/sitemap">Sitemap</a></div>
```

Assuming this is the case, the replacement you want is so simple you don't even need a regex: find all href attributes beginning "/", and add the domain part (I'll use "http://example.com") to their beginning to make them absolute:

```
$scraped_html = str_replace('href="/', 'href="http://example.com/', $scraped_html);
```

Comment: You sir are a god! If I could shake your hand I would. Thank-you so much.